# Google_ServiceException while using Mirror api php sdk

Tags: php, google-mirror-api

I'm getting errors while running Google Glass quick starter **PHP** project using Mirror **API**. I've seen a similar question in the forum but in my case i've enabled the Mirror api in the **Google API** console. We are working in a group using a new Gmail account(that aptly describes our group) which has been tied up to our Glass very recently.

In the error log it says:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET 
https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline?maxResults=3&key=xxxxxxxxxxx: (403)
Access Not Configured'
```

Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated.

Thanking the experts in advance.

**The complete error log:**

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline?maxResults=3&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: (403) Access Not Configured' in /var/www/mirror-quickstart-php/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php:66\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/mirror-quickstart-php/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#1 /var/www/mirror-quickstart-php/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))\n#2 /var/www/mirror-quickstart-php/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_MirrorService.php(434): Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array)\n#3 /var/www/mirror-quickstart-php/index.php(142): google_TimelineServiceResource->listTimeline(Array)\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/mirror-quickstart-php/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66

**And in the index.php line 142 shows:**

```
//Load cool stuff to show them.
$timeline = $mirror_service->timeline->listTimeline(array('maxResults'=>'3'));
```

Comment: Can you post the specific section of code where this error is being caused?